# Replacing Values by ID

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset that I am looking to replace values of the employees status to be just one value off their most recent row of history I am using pandas and numpy in this code. This is what I have:

```
 ID    Start_Date     End_Date      Emp_Status
 1     11/23/2021     1/12/2022       Active
 1     1/12/2022      3/1/2022        Active
 1     3/1/2022       7/3/2022        Termed
 2     7/19/2018      10/11/2018      Active
 2     10/11/2018     3/30/2019       Termed
 2     3/30/2022      9/7/2022        Active
```

And this is what I want:

```
ID     Start_Date      End_Date     Emp_Status       Status
1      11/23/2021      1/12/2022      Active         Termed
1      1/12/2022       3/1/2022       Active         Termed
1      3/1/2022        7/3/2022       Termed         Termed 
2      7/19/2018       10/11/2018     Active         Active
2      10/11/2018      3/30/2019      Termed         Active
2      3/30/2022       9/7/2022       Active         Active
```

I tried to get the last record by person and using a for loop to fill the rest, here is the cide I used:

```
Status = [] 
for i in df.groupby('ID')['Emp_Status'].tail(1):
    if 'Active' in i:
        df['Emp_Status'].replace("Termed","Active")
        Status.append(df['Emp_Status'])
    else:
        df['Emp_Status'].replace("Active","Termed")
        Status.append(df['Emp_Status']
df['Status'] = df['Emp_Status']
```

when I do this their is no change and I copy the Emp_Status column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as below, same as your idea getting last status of each ID, convert to dictionary, just would efficient to call, next I used lambda fdunction to go on each row id and check, give new status.

```
dic  = df.groupby('ID').agg({'Emp_Status': 'last'}).to_dict()['Emp_Status']
df['status'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: dic[x])
df
```